# Use Firebase Emulator without an internet connection

Tags: firebase, firebase-tools

It seems that when you use the firebase emulator but have no internet connection you can't load the firebase scripts like `http://localhost:5000/__/firebase/8.4.2/firebase-app.js` the local server that is created by firebase emulator must be actually fetching the `firebase-app.js` from google firebase servers and serving that back through localhost.

Is it possible to use Firebase Emulator without an internet connection?

Answer (score 1):

The `__` local handler here does not do much more than redirect the SDKs on the internet. Otherwise the emulator suite would have to include a lot of versions of all Firebase SDKs, which is not feasible.

So if you want full offline development, you'll have to include the SDKs from a local path that is part of your own web app, or ensure they are preloaded and cached from a CDN before you go offline.